How can I clean out this black grime, inside an unopenable motor chamber?
Compressed air, hair dryer, vacuum cleaner couldn't remove this black grit off the side glass, or blades. Toothpicks, cotton swabs couldn't reach the sides.
How else can I clear away, and wipe out, this black grime?
As this motor works fine,  I don't want to waste $200 USD on a new motor. I don't know what this black smut is. I don't fire or smoke or burn anything. Whole-house central HEPA is installed into my home's HVAC.




That appears to be some grease leakage, and it looks like it's inside the plastic motor housing. You'd have to disassemble the thing. It's absolutely not something I'd waste time on, though. What problem is it causing?

What we are seeing at the top of the motor (in the photos)... is that some kind of impeller or fan blade?

The fan is held on by a nut.  A picture of the bottom might help to see a way to undo.  There seem to be white lines that might be threads, so the bottom might unscrew.

@isherwood This motor may blow out all this black grit, if I don't get rid of it.

@SteveI I just added bottom pics.

@crip659 I just added bottom pics.

What device did this motor come out of? Dos it suck air on the dirty side and push out air on the clean side? And why does it need to be cleaned? Is it in sight of passersby on an otherwise clean display?
